# Are there any documented uses of Clojure/Clojurescript for devops and/or automation testing?

Tags: testing, clojure, automated-tests, devops, clojurescript

I am looking for something along the same lines as this article: ["Go With Go(Lang): Features and Testing Frameworks"](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/go-with-go-lang-features-and-testing-frameworks-ab39c51d0c66), featuring Clojure/Clojurescript.  Similarly, any book(s) that contain examples of Clojure/Clojurescript being used as to create devops/test-automation applications, would also help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague, but Clojure is IMHO the best general-purpose computer language (no surprise since you asked on a Clojure site!).

One solution that might work for you [is the Babashka tool](https://github.com/borkdude/babashka).  It allows you to turn Clojure code in to a stand-alone executable. So, instead of using quirky, fragile `bash` scripts, you can write a robust & powerful Clojure program that has the instant startup & low memory usage of a Go or C program.

For more general purposes, you can write a complete general-purpose Clojure program and interop with the outside O.S. with [a function like `tupelo.misc/shell-cmd`](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/20.08.27b/api/tupelo.misc#shell-cmd) or the [original Clojure version from clojure.java.shell](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.java.shell/sh).  I have used this to drive AWS CLI functions, for example listing, cloning, and deleting RDS database instances.

The sky is the limit (along with your imagination).

---

### Update

I forgot to mention GraalVM.  It allows you to compile Clojure code into a static executable (the same as produced by a C/C++ program).  Here is [a Clojure/GraalVM demo project](https://github.com/io-tupelo-demo/graalvm) that creates a "Hello World" program even faster and more memory efficient than a Python script!  Enjoy!

Answer (score 3):

I am the developer behind [spire](https://epiccastle.io/spire/), a clojure DSL for idempotent machine provisioning over ssh. I built it using [GraalVM](https://www.graalvm.org/) and [sci](https://github.com/borkdude/sci). I have also used it for automated testing.

Presently I am working on making it a [babashka pod](https://github.com/babashka/pod-registry), so soon you will be able to use its functionality directly from [babashka](https://github.com/babashka/babashka/).

Answer (score 1):

I do virtually all my AWS manipulations using [aws-api](https://github.com/cognitect-labs/aws-api). The dev-ops experience via clojure is much better than using bash/shell scripts and the AWS CLI.